# Filter subpages and add classes in Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I'm using node sorting to determine pages within a subfolder in Jekyll. This image shows my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

So let's say I have a page at http://localhost/grain/ahvsuperb/ (shown below as `index.html`). Navigating to this page would show the class `on` added to that link. That works fine.

Where I'm running into trouble is when I navigate to a page such as http://localhost/grain/ahvsuperb/features/. When I navigate to that page, *both* `index` AND `features` have the `on` class added to them. Any insight as to how to filter that out with Liquid?

```
<div class="content_nav">
  <ul class="content_nav">
    {% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | sort: 'weight' %}
    {% for node in sorted_pages %}
      {% if node.title != nil and node.url != '/' %}
      {% capture nodediff %}{{ page.url | remove:node.url }}{% endcapture %}
      <li><a {% if nodediff != page.url %}class="on" {% endif %}href="{{node.url}}">{{node.title}}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <li style="float:right"><a class="brochured" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="#brochuredl">Brochure</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a class="quoted" href="#">Get a Quote</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Did you have some repository to show ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `{% capture nodediff %}{{ page.url | remove:node.url }}{% endcapture %}` then `{% if nodediff != page.url %}` are not returning expected page determination.

This will do the job :

```
<div class="content-nav">
  <ul class="content-nav">
    {% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | sort: 'weight' %}
    {% for node in sorted_pages %}
      {% if node.title != nil and node.url != '/' %}
      <li><a {% if node.url == page.url %}class="on" {% endif %}href="{{node.url}}">{{node.title}}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <li style="float:right"><a class="brochured" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="#brochuredl">Brochure</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a class="quoted" href="#">Get a Quote</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks David!

Comment: So I'm going to reopen this... Now that I've continued working on this, I've added another "section". The problem I'm having is all pages are showing ALL subpages, no matter what the parent is. You can see the folder structure [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4txa9yufjpykhx7/Screenshot%202015-12-17%2012.23.06.png?dl=0). Let me know if you have any insight.

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33305868/1548376 or this http://thinkshout.com/blog/2014/12/creating-dynamic-menus-in-jekyll/