# Jekyll linked documents in collections?

Tags: jekyll

In Jekyll's Front Matter, is there a way to make references to another document?

I have a custom collection, and would like to add meta-data in each document such as "parent-topic" (a link to the parent), and "children" (an array of documents), or "related-topics".

With such a reference I could access the linked documents' meta-data, such as their title, url, or other arbitrary data.

The idea is a hierarchy of documentation, with topics, sub-topics, sub-sub-topics, etc. And a topic page could show a list of child topics, or a breadcrumb for the parent topics, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Real question that deserve a real answer. I also got this documentation problem. Following [advise from Ben Balter](http://ben.balter.com/2015/02/20/jekyll-collections/), I started to use `collections`. The idea was to make

- a table of content reflecting topic/sub-topics arrangement,
- a breadcrumb on each page

I gave up because it was simplest to code against `pages`. So, here's how I do documentation with pages.

### Prerequisites :

- documentation is in a folder eg : documentation
- `permalink` is set to `pretty` in _config.yml
- folders hierarchy describes documentation organization

**example**

```
documentation
|--index.html
|--chapter-1
|  |--index.html
|
|--chapter-2
|  |--index.html
|  |
|  |--part-1
|  |  |--index.html
|  |  |--subpart-1
|  |     |--index.html
|  |--part-2
|  |  |--index.html
|  |
|  |--part-3.html
```

Note : `documentation/chapter-2/part-2/index.html` can also be `documentation/chapter-2/part-2.html`, because `permalink` is set to `pretty`, generated page will be at `documentation/chapter-2/part-2/index.html`.

- Pages at a same level are sorted depending on a `weight` front matter variable. This can be anything you want.
  Numbering by tenth allows easy insertion for new doc.

**example front matter**

```
---
title: My title
weight: 10
---
```

- documentation get default variables values from `_config.yml`

**example**

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "documentation"
      type: pages

    values:
      isDoc: true # allows quick extraction from site.pages
      layout: page
```

Once those prerequisites are in place, it's easy to print a table of content and a breadcrumb.

### Table of content

**_includes/show-children.html**

```
{% assign parentDir = include.dir %}
{% if parentDir == nil %}<h1>You must specify a root directory</h1>{% endif %}

{% assign allDocs = include.docs %}
{% if allDocs == nil %}{% assign allDocs = site.pages | sort: "weight" %}{% endif %}

{% assign level = include.level %}
{% if level == nil %}{% assign level = parentDir | remove_first: "/" | split:"/" | size %}{% endif %}

{% assign maxLevel = include.maxLevel %}
{% if maxLevel == nil %}{% assign maxLevel = 100 %}{% endif %}

{% assign nextLevel = level | plus : 1 %}

{% comment %}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Looking for all page in this path with the same level (siblings)
This avoid to deep recursion and error like :
__ Liquid Exception: Nesting too deep __
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++{% endcomment %}

{% assign siblings = "" | split: "/" %}
{% for s in allDocs %}
    {% assign sPageLevel = s.url | remove_first: "/" | split:"/" | size %}
    {% if sPageLevel == level and s.url contains parentDir %}
        {% if s.title %}{% assign siblings = siblings | push: s %}{% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<ul>
{% for p in siblings %}
    <li><a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{p.url}}"{%if p.url == page.url%} class="active"{%endif%}>{{ p.title }}</a>
    {% if nextLevel <= maxLevel %}
      {% include show-children.html dir=p.dir docs=allDocs level=nextLevel maxLevel=maxLevel %}
    {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% comment %}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Because all variables are globales (all includes have the same scope)
we restore level and nextLevel variables to parent values
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++{% endcomment %}
{% assign level = level | minus : 1 %}
{% assign nextLevel = nextLevel | minus : 1 %}
```

#### Use

This include can be called with several arguments :

**dir**  : root dir to explore (ie : /documentation)

**docs** : an array of pages - default to site.pages

**level**: level at which we start printing (/documentation is at level 1,
       /documentation/chapter-1 is at level 2, and so on)
       Default to 'dir' level

**maxLevel**: where to stop to print - default to 100

```
Extracting documentation pages
{% assign documents = site.pages | where: "isDoc", true | sort: "weight" %}
{% assign dir = "documentation" %}

This will print all documentation hierachy
{% include show-children.html dir=dir docs=documents %}

This will start printing at level 2
{% include show-children.html dir=dir docs=documents level=2 %}

This stop printing at level 2
{% include show-children.html dir=dir docs=documents maxLevel=2 %}
```

On page layout if you just want to print page children you can do :

```
{% assign documents = site.pages | where: "isDoc", true | sort: "weight" %}
{% assign level = page.dir | remove_first: "/" | split:"/" | size %}
{% assign childrenLevel = level | plus : 1 %}
{% include show-children.html docs=documents dir=page.dir level=childrenLevel %}
```

### Breadcrumb

**_includes/breadcrumb.html**

```
{% assign minLevel = include.minLevel %}
{% if minLevel == nil %}{% assign minLevel = 1 %}{% endif %}

<div class="breadcrumb">
<p>You are here : </p>
{% assign documents = site.pages | where: "isDoc", true | sort: "weight" %}
{% include get-parents.html page=page minLevel=minLevel docs=documents %}
<p>{{ page.title }}</p>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.breadcrumb p { display: inline; }
.breadcrumb p+p+p:before { content:"» "; }
</style>
```

**_includes/get-parents.html**

```
{% assign currentPage = include.page %}
{% assign minLevel    = include.minLevel %}
{% assign allDocs     = include.docs %}
{% assign pageLevel   = currentPage.dir | remove_first: "/" | split:"/" | size %}
{% assign parentLevel = pageLevel | minus: 1 %}
{% if parentLevel >= minLevel %}
    {% for p in allDocs %}
        {% assign pPageLevel = p.dir | remove_first: "/" | split:"/" | size %}
        {% if pPageLevel == parentLevel and currentPage.dir contains p.dir %}
            {% include get-parents.html page=p minLevel=minLevel docs=allDocs %}
            <p><a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{p.url}}">{{ p.title }}</a></p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

#### Use

Print `Documentation > chapter 1 > part 1`

```
{% include breadcrumb.html %}
```

Print `Chapter 1 > part 1`

```
{% include breadcrumb.html minLevel=2 %}
```

Can it be more simple ?

[Working code can be found here](http://statiktest.github.io/docWithJekyll/).

Comment: Thanks for the full answer! It will take me a while to digest... Unfortunately it starts by moving from collection to pages...

Comment: It can be renaming `_documentation` to `documentation` and your collection is now a pages folder. Add some `weight` to order your items and you're done.

Comment: Will it convert .md files to .html like in collections?

Comment: Indeed it does. Just checked. I'm wondering what does collections give me that pages don't now...

Comment: Yes, it will convert .md to .html like it does for any md page or post.

Comment: The idea of collections is to have grouped datas that you can work on just by calling `site.myCollection`. In order to work the same way, you have to use my tricky way, but pages have more properties to work on programatically. Remember that collections are still an experimental feature.

Comment: Do your code snippets assume that all pages are generated as folder/index.html ? Mine are parent-topic/index.html, parent-topic/sub-topic.html (meaning the final leaf is not a folder). I think because of this when I try your code it does not show me the last folder in the breadcrumbs (folder before the current page)....

Comment: Did you set `permalink: pretty` in your `_config.yml`, then restart `jekyll serve` ?

Comment: Can you give an example hierarchy you want to produce ?

Comment: I had the same thing but without 'pretty' so mypage.md would be generated as mypage.html.  But I can live with 'pretty'. I'll restructure my links.

Comment: FYI, when overriding the default minLevel, if you start going deep, somehow the level shows up in the middle of nowhere. I worked around by not overriding the minLevel and instead put a hide_in_breadcrumb variable in any page I don't want there.